# Unit testing a method in which I am doing a dependency injection

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, rspec

I have a terminal app with two classes: Todo and TodoApp. The method below lives in TodoApp, I would like to unit test this method and keep it isolated in my test. Since I am doing a dependency injection within the method, how could I mock that? (@todos is an empty array in TodoApp initialize)

```
 def add(task, day, todo = Todo)
    @todos.push(todo.new(task, day))
    return "#{task} was added to your todos"
 end
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I think of the benefits of dependency injection is you don't have to mock. Can you show an example of your unit test?

Comment: Sure, do you want me to write it here in the comment area?

Comment: No, edit the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I imagine your code looks like this.

```
class TodoApp
  def initialize 
    @todos = []
  end

  def add(task, day, todo = Todo)
    @todos.push(todo.new(task, day))
    return "#{task} was added to your todos"
  end
end
```

This is NOT injecting the empty array into the TodoApp. And, therefore you are going to have difficulty accessing it from the tests.

But, if your TodoApp object looked like this:

```
class TodoApp
  def initialize(todos = [])
    @todos = todos
  end

  def add(task, day, todo = Todo)
    @todos.push(todo.new(task, day))
    return "#{task} was added to your todos"
  end
end
```

Now you are injecting something into TodoApp that can be mocked, or even just evaluated:

```
describe TodoApp do
  subject(:app) { described_class.new(todos) }

  let(:todos) { [] }

  describe '#add' do
    subject(:add) { app.add(task, day) }

    let(:task) { 'task' }
    let(:day) { 'day' }

    it 'pushes the item on the list of todos' do
      expect { add }.to change { todos.length }.by(1)
    end
  end
end
```